# Picture won't change by modifying "src"

Tags: javascript, html, image, dom, src

Alright, I'm trying to write yet another program to practice my Javascript, and I've hit another roadblock.  For now, the program is simple.  Select from a drop-down list from a list of ethnicities (currently limited to "Swede" and "Italian"), and then the program will write a short description of their (stereotypical) appearance, and post a picture.  Or rather, change the default "Mystery man" picture.

The first part works fine.  The text changes depending on if you select "Swede" or "Italian."  The picture part does not.  The image will not change from its default "Mystery man" picture.  Why is that?

```js
var ethnicities = [{
    name: "Swede",
    eyecolor: "blue",
    hairtex: "straight",
    fp: 1,
    pic: "Swedish.png"
  },
  {
    name: "Italian",
    eyecolor: "brown",
    hairtex: "curly",
    fp: 2,
    pic: "Italian.png"
  }
];


function description() {
  var desc = "The " + ethnicities[document.EPF.EPDD.value].name +
    " is " + ethnicities[document.EPF.EPDD.value].eyecolor + "-eyed and " +
    ethnicities[document.EPF.EPDD.value].hairtex + "-haired." +
    "";



  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = desc;
  document.getElementbyId("picture").src = ethnicities[document.EPF.EPDD.value].pic;
  //so weird, it just doesn't chnage it.  It doesn't matter what I put on the
  //right of the equal sign.
}
```

```html
<p>Ethnicity presets:</p>
<form name="EPF">
  <select name="EPDD">
    <option value="0">Swede</option>
    <option value="1">Italian</option>
   
    </select>

  <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="description()">

</form>
<p id="demo"> </p>

<img id="picture" src="Mystery man.png" alt="unknown">
```

Comment: Typo, `getElementbyId` should be `getElementById`

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you!  It's amazing how the little things get you in programming!

Comment: You should delete this.

Comment: It says I can't delete it because others have answered it.

Comment: It will be closed shortly.

Comment: Surely looking at your console would have shown you this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementbyId("picture").src = ethnicities[documen...
```

should be

```
document.getElementById("picture").src = ethnicities[documen...
```

You forgot to capitalise the 'b' in 'elementById'

Answer (score 0):

This is just a syntax error do not forget always look console to detect the problem.You need just write upper case "B" in  " document.getElementById() " .